# send combobox value to parameterized query Ms Access

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010, parameterized-query

I do have a problem to send a value of combobox to a parameterized query : what i did so far is :

[image]

[image]

but when i execute my app the pop up below is showin, and asking to pass a parameter
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you triple-checked the name? I suggest using meaningful control names, not `Control87`. Is the form open when you run the query? Is it a subform?

Comment: i'm passing parameter from a form [Passer QCM] to another form, modifiable43 is the name of the combobox ;

Comment: Are you running the query from the open form ? How did you construct your query using MS-Access intellisense - it should automatically populate the combo box name if you start typing it correctly